# set default value of the first entry made in attribute table in qgis

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I will make an example so it's easier to understand what I am trying to do. So let's say I have an Attribute table with 3 columns(district-name, building, district-number). What I want to do is the following: When the first entry is made, I want QGIS to set the district-number of the first entry to be the default number for every other entry that is going to be made with the same district-name. With entry I mean when you create a feature. I can't really provide any code, because I don't even know if I have to do this with python or if I can directly do this in QGIS.

Comment: Create a form using QtCreator?

Comment: What do you mean with create a form with QtCreator?